# CSS borders brainteaser

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS that creates a blue speech bubble (JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C5N2c/:

```
<div class="bubble">Content</div>

.bubble 
{
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    left:30px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: blue;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: blue solid 6px;

}

.bubble:after 
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 10px 10px;
    border-color: blue transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    top: -10px;
    left: 26px;
}

.bubble:before 
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 15px 15px;
    border-color: blue transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    top: -21px;
    left: 21px;
}
```

I want to add a 1px red border around the edge of this bubble, including the small speech arrow. How can I do this? It needs to be IE8 compliant.

Comment: This is kinda overhead to do this with css. I'd use a image vor the speech arrow and attach a border around the the bubble.

Comment: You need to make the border around the speech arrow portion by overlaying one element to mask another, which you almost have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look a this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sxM57/), though I havent been able to test in IE8..

The CSS:

```
.bubble 
{
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    left:30px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: blue;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: red solid 1px;
    z-index:2;
}

.bubble:after 
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 9px 9px;
    border-color: blue transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    top: -9px;
    left: 26px;
}

.bubble:before 
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 11px 12px;
    border-color: red transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    top: -12px;
    left: 24px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**See working version on [jsFidde](http://jsfiddle.net/aleation/Ahujr/)**

I did it sometime ago, you can just change the colours, It's not tested on IE, I am currently on OSX and it's a mess trying to view it on IE xD

html:

```
<div class="dialog">
    <div class="triangleOutline">
        <div class="triangle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="dialogBox">
        Hello!<br>
        I'm a full CSS fancy dialog box :D
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
body{
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: "Arimo";
    background: #eee;
}

.triangle,
.triangleOutline{
    position:relative;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: solid transparent;
    border-width: 7px;
    border-bottom-color: #aaf;
}

.triangleOutline{left: 15px;}

.triangle{
    top: -6px; /* outline's width - 1 */
    left: -7px; /* outline's width */
    border-bottom-color: white;
}

.dialogBox{
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid #aaf;
    padding: 0.75em;
    border-radius: 3px;
    min-height: 1.5em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
```

Just change the colors as you like, I guess you are not using THOSE colors right? XD

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
.bubble 
{
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    left:30px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: blue;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: blue solid 6px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px red;
}

.bubble:after 
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 15px 15px;
    border-color: blue transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    top: -19px;
    left: 21px;
}

.bubble:before 
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 15px 15px;
    border-color: red transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    top: -21px;
    left: 21px;
}
```

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C5N2c/28/).